# Populate form with data from another form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a page with a small tour, within the tour points are inputs. Also on this page is another form, these forms have similar inputs including first, last name, etc...

If the user inputs their first name into form 1, how can I populate the first name field of form 2?

This is form 1:

```
<form role="form" id="inviteform3" class="form-inline" action="name.php" method="POST">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="name" placeholder="First Name" 
id="hello" autocomplete="off" style="margin-top:10px">
                            </div>
                            <center>
                            <span id="start">Let's get started, <span id="result"></span></span>


                            <button class="btn btn-brand btn-sm next-screen animated bounceInUp" 
id="go" style="margin-top:5px; display:none" href="#services" data-animation-delay=".5s"> 
Let's Go!</button></center>
    <button class="btn btn-block btn-brand btn-xs invitebtn3" id="casi" type="submit" 
style="margin-top:5px"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i> Submit</button>

</form>
```

This is form 2:

```
<form role="form" id="inviteform" class="form-inline" 
action="http://omnihustle.net/demo/invitations/invite_request" type="POST"><div 
class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="InputFirstName" placeholder="First 
Name">
                            </div>
    <div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="InputLastName" placeholder="Last 
Name">
                            </div>

<div class="form-group">
<input type="email" class="form-control input-sm" id="InputEmail" placeholder="Email">
  </div>

<button class="btn btn-brand btn-sm invitebtn" type="submit" data-toggle="modal" data-
target=".bs-example-modal-sm"><i class="fa fa-check fa-fw"></i> Invite Me</button></form>
```

Here is my php file which the form is sent to:

```
<html>
<body>

<?php session_start(); ?>

<?php
 if  (isset($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['name'])) {
    $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
 }
?>

<?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?>

</body>

</html>
```

Jquery has not worked since I am unable to enter html into the "value" field of the form, so what is the alternative?

Here is what ive tried;

```
<script>

$(document).on("ready", function(){
//Form action
$("#inviteform3").on("submit", function(event){
// Stop submit event
event.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
    type:'POST', 
    url: 'name.php',
    data:$('#inviteform3').serialize(), 
    success: function(response)  
    {
        $('#inviteform3').find('#result').html(response);
        $('.coupontooltip5').find('#result2').html(response);
        $('#announcement').find('#result3').html(response);
        $('#announcement2').find('#result4').html(response);
        $('#progressbutton').find('#result5').html(response);
        $('#inviteform').find('#result6').html(response);


    }});
});
});

</script>
```

I have tried inputting "span id="result6" into the "value" tag of the input and the form does not allow the function, just shows the html as the default value of the input..

Comment: `Jquery has not worked since I am unable to enter html into the "value" field of the form` You should post your failing attempt because for sure jQuery works for it

Comment: I've added what I have tried, @A. Wolff. My mistake is probably very silly.

Comment: FYI, `$(document).on("ready", handler);` is really bad syntax for the jquery ready handler.  Now what is `response`?

Comment: not entirely sure, @A. Wolff. Possibly some sort of shorthand in ajax to fire the initial function on success? I completely made that up.

Comment: In success callback: `console.log(response);`, so expected response in console? You have to learn how to debug javascript using console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a 'keyup' handler which copy the content to the second field. Add the following lines into the 'ready' handler.

```
$('#hello').on('keyup', function() {
  $('#InputFirstName').val($(this).val());
});
```

If you add a 'change' handler instead of this 'keyup' handler, the handler is called only after the the field loses the focus.

By the way, name.php does not work. session_start() must be called before any output is made. Hence:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<html>
<body>
```